# Is EnumSet Thread-safe? My test show me it is safe

Tags: java, switch-statement

These is my test code, and the output tells me it is thread-safe. Am I wrong?

I think the so-called thread-safety means that the `run(){}` method is atomic.

```
    import java.util.EnumMap;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import com.enumTest.enumStateMac.Input;

public class TestEnumMapSafe implements Runnable {

    private String name = "";

    public TestEnumMapSafe(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    static Map<Input, Input> enumHashMap = new EnumMap<Input, Input>(Input.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        TestEnumMapSafe testEnumMapSafe1 = new TestEnumMapSafe("Thread_1");
        TestEnumMapSafe testEnumMapSafe2 = new TestEnumMapSafe("Thread_2");
        TestEnumMapSafe testEnumMapSafe3 = new TestEnumMapSafe("Thread_3");

            testEnumMapSafe1.run();
            testEnumMapSafe2.run();
            testEnumMapSafe3.run();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            enumHashMap.put(Input.ABORT_TRANSACTION, Input.ABORT_TRANSACTION);
            enumHashMap.put(Input.CHIPS, Input.CHIPS);
            enumHashMap.put(Input.QUARTER, Input.QUARTER);
            System.out.println("this.name: " + this.name + "  enumHashMap.keySet() : " + enumHashMap.keySet());
            enumHashMap.clear();
        }

    }
}
/*this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_1  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_2  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
this.name: Thread_3  enumHashMap.keySet() : [QUARTER, CHIPS, ABORT_TRANSACTION]
*/
```

Can someone help? Is something wrong with my test for "thread-safe"?

Comment: What do you think you're going to do with a thread-unsafe enum? *Edit* it?

Comment: you don't even have multiple threads running, how can you say you did a test?

Comment: I think the question is whether EnumMap is thread-safe.  The answer can be found in its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html):  No, it is not.

Comment: @VGR  how to test it ????

Comment: Testing thread-safety is almost impossible, because it's nondeterministic -- you can't necessarily force the conditions necessary to break the code.

Comment: there must be a way!@LouisWasserman

Comment: @kolossus   i mean EnumMap....doc say it's not safe.....i want show and test...........

Comment: @Transcendence   i think if it's not thread-safe,output should be "enumHashMap.keySet() : [ ]"

Comment: @ZhangShuo: Why do you think there must be a way?  If there were, testing for concurrency bugs would be easy.

Comment: your test is running in a single thread. you're not testing thread safety at all.

Comment: didn't you find it a bit odd that thread 1,2,3 did not mix at all? that thread 1 ran first, then thread 2, then thread3?

Comment: @Transcendence   why??  testEnumMapSafe1.run();
                                           testEnumMapSafe2.run();
                                           testEnumMapSafe3.run();      i m so wonder,could you show me the correct code on it????  thanks very much ,Dude

Comment: you clearly don't know how to run multiple threads, i suggest you read up on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From EnumSet javadoc:

`* Like most collection implementations, <tt>EnumSet</tt> is not
 * synchronized.  If multiple threads access an enum set concurrently, and at
 * least one of the threads modifies the set, it should be synchronized
 * externally.`

EnumSet is 'safe' only in the sense it will not throw any exception if used concurrently. However it must be synchronized or you risk seeing outdated version of your data.

As for testing thread safety. As other people mentioned, you cannot prove your program is synchronized correctly by running some tests. You can observe some wrong behavior due to lack of synchronization but there is no guarantee you will.

Comment: If multiple threads access an enum set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it should be synchronized externally. This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the enum set. If no such object exists, the set should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedSet(java.util.Set) method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access:

Comment: how  to test  it's not safe....  by the way ,how to test HashMap is not thread safe?????????

Answer (score 0):

To actually get your test doing something multithreaded, try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    TestEnumMapSafe testEnumMapSafe1 = new TestEnumMapSafe("Thread_1");
    TestEnumMapSafe testEnumMapSafe2 = new TestEnumMapSafe("Thread_2");
    TestEnumMapSafe testEnumMapSafe3 = new TestEnumMapSafe("Thread_3");

    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    executor.submit(testEnumMapSafe1);
    executor.submit(testEnumMapSafe2);
    executor.submit(testEnumMapSafe3);

    executor.shutdown();

    //wait some arbitrary period to allow test to complete
    executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

However, as others have said, this is likely an exercise in futility. You might see issues, you might not.